# Advanced conditional compilation in C#

Tags: c#, conditional-compilation

I'm exploring the possibilities of advanced conditional compilation in C#. The case of my work is that I need to have a different behavior depending on the configuration of the project. I do not mean banal `DEBUG`/`RELEASE`.

So for example, this is my code:

```
namespace Common
{
    public struct ActionResult
    {
        int id;
        string summary;
    }

    public class Widget
    {
        public ActionResult Process(out string path)
        {
            // A few lines of code
            path = "path_to_file";
            var result = DoAction(path);
            // A few lines of code
            return result;
        }

        protected virtual ActionResult DoAction(string path)
        {
#if RELEASE_TARGET_1
            HelperForTarget_1();
#elif RELEASE_TARGET_2
            // Do other action...
#endif

#if TRACE_TO_CONSOLE
            return new ConsoleLogger(new ActionResult());
#else
            return new ActionResult();
#endif
        }

        [Conditional("RELEASE_TARGET_1")]
        private void HelperForTarget_1()
        {
            // Initializing a pair or triple of class fields.
        }
    }
}
```

First, `#if/#endif` looks very ugly. Everyone knows that auto-renaming does not work in excluded areas (I know that ReSharper can, but still). The code looks like a leatherface sewn from pieces. It is hard to perceive and hard for support;

Secondly, the `ConditionalAttribute` can not always be applied to a method. For example, a method can return a value or have out parameters. One option is to split `DoAction` into a bunch of small methods and still apply `ConditionalAttribute` to them. However, to compensate for the return value and out parameters, you will have to complicate the class with fields that will only be needed for one of several implementations. Fields will likely have to wrap `#if/#endif`, WTF!

Third, polymorphism. Extract an abstract `WidgetBase` that includes general behavior for all implementations and create concrete versions, such as `WidgetForTarget1`, `WidgetForTarget2`, etc. which implement specific behavior. It sounds good, but concrete widgets can not inherit classes, only interfaces. Sometimes it is fundamentally unacceptable. If I extract the interface `IWidget`, then concrete implementations will contain a lot of copy-paste - it's bad and hard to maintain, nice try.

I started looking towards `partial` classes/methods, in the hope that there is a workaround, but no. There is an ugly way: extract the compilation-dependent code in different files of the partial class and wrap the entire file `#if/#endif`, but this is the ugliness I'm trying to get rid of, damn!

I thought about compiling modules (`.netmodule`) but in fact, it's assembly, except that without a manifest.

I was thinking about assembly binding (redirecting versions) using publisher policies, etc. but it's not that, in any case, this is the use of politicians for other purposes, besides, it's still difficult to maintain.

In short, I am desperate and refuse to believe that there is no good way for this case of work. It is noteworthy that in C ++ this is solved quite simply: I can declare the class in the header file, then implement the general behavior in one .cpp file, and the configuration-dependent behavior in other cpp files and apply these .cpp files for compilation depending on my settings solution.

Comment: Conditional compilation is not something you can really use to organize a project. As you have already described, it does not scale. Why not use `static` methods, that is procedural organization? It would be an improvement.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I'm sorry, but I did not quite understand what you mean when you talk about using `static` methods. I do not see a way out in `static` methods. I want details of your point of view, thank you in advance.

Comment: I am just saying that you should keep it simple. Inheritance is one of many organizational techniques in C#. You can write static methods that check a condition and then act accordingly. Methods can be passed as arguments to other methods via delegates. Methods can be statically dispatched based on unrelated types, forming ad-hoc organization, using extension methods. And there are many ways to combine these and use them alongside polymorphism as well. Also, don't forget you can use _global variables_. A bad idea? Yes. Better than using `#ifdef` to structure your code? Yes.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, Your advice makes me think. I roughly understand your idea and this approach is different from the usual workflow for me. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

An interface (or even base class) which has different implementations depending on the build target would work, and be conceptually similar to the header/implementation approach in C/C++. I'm not sure whether one can have different source files depending on the build target for a project in Visual Studio -- perhaps it will be necessary to maintain distinct projects. But still that seems like an improvement.

To separate the interface from the implementation is a common design pattern to facilitate testing.

One can also construct Visual Studio solutions and projects synthetically, e.g. with [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake), or simply use `make` right away, potentially as a custom build in Visual Studio.

Comment: I agree that manual project / solution management gives maximum flexibility (via cmake or direct MSBuild). However, the work of the team with the structure of the project will become more complicated and the probability of errors related to the human factor will increase. Managing the building with the IDE is preferable.

Answer (score -1):

> if/#endif

must die. Make the check via static initialisation or in the constructor of an object, if you don't have many of those.